# default view resolution in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am a spring newbie and have a question about view resolution. I am changing a webapp that I downloaded online and it uses the simple view resolver strategy:

```
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

and I keep getting 404 errors for view resolution and I am suspecting that it uses some sort of rewriting / filtering mechanism. Is there a log that I can view in tomcat / Spring class that I can override in order to understand what file is Spring trying to look for when resolving an incoming request?

I understand the operation of `InternalResourceViewResolver` which strips file name extensions. But what if the request does not have an extension? For instance:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo")
protected ModelMap render() { return new ModelMap(); }
```

Then what is the view name that will be resolved to in this case?

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-log4j-integration-example/) for log4j integration

Spring-mvc doesn't use any file for request handling, it uses controllers and requestmapping to map the request to a controller and respective method if any.

The InternalResourceViewResolver that you have written Resolves “view name” that is returned from the controller class to a JSP page residing in /WEB-INF/view/ directory.

an example

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController{

@RequestMapping("/home")
public String homeMapper(Model model) {        
    return "home";
}
}
```

here homeMapper method will be called if you try to access "home" and as it returns home the relative jsp to be rendered is "home.jsp" should be present in /WEB-INF/view/

For more information see spring mvc reference or any tutorial.